# select.val returning undefined in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing the following:

```
$('#clear-button').click(function () {
        var clearableFieldArray = $('.clearable-field');
        var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(clearableFieldArray);

        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if (i == 6) {
                array[i].val('');
            } else {
                array[i].val('All');
            }
        }
    });
```

when I do `console.log(array[i])` it prints the correct elements and children, however when I try to access the `.val()` it keeps returning undefined, why is it doing that

Comment: Is it a jQuery object? Wrap it with a jQuery selector if not.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Your logic seems a little off. If you want to get the 7th `.clearable-field` element you could just use `$('.clearable-field').eq(6).val('')`

Comment: What is $('.clearable-field');

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if its one of the first 6 elements, its a select, so set the value to "All" which is an option I have, otherwise the 7th element is a text input, so set the val to ""

Comment: I added $(array[i]) and its working, thank you @Tomanow, add it as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `$(array[i])` with the jQuery selector because it looks like you are not selecting a jQuery object but a regular DOM object.

Answer (score 1):

> if its one of the first 6 elements, its a select, so set the value to "All" which is an option I have, otherwise the 7th element is a text input, so set the val to ""

In this case you can simplify your code without the need for arrays:

```
$('#clear-button').click(function () {
    $('input.clearable-field').val('');
    $('select.clearable-field').val('All');
});
```

Comment: this will select all the selects/inputs with class 'clearable-field'? - nice, I like the refactor

Comment: That's right. If you want to only affect a group of them I would suggest traversing the DOM to find a common parent to restrict the selector to. It's better semantically and avoids ugly array munging code.